# Getting data from a PLC to a raspberry pi with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, plc

I am programming a script to communicate with a S7-300 PLC. I have set an ethernet connect on both devices (PLC and Raspberry pi). 
Ip PLC 192.168.0.1
IP raspberry pi 192.168.5
I was just trying to get a connection with a script like  this:

```
import socket
host = '192.168.0.1'
port = 34964
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))
s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
print("got connection from: " + str(addr))
```

In my plc i have only installed the IP address and that it is networked with ethernet.

But when i am trying to connect with the plc i was having always the same error "Connection refused".

Can somebody help me please or give me some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Run `nmap` on the PLC. BTW: Since you're using a normal network, the fact that it runs on an RPi is completely irrelevant. If it works on a different machine but not on the RPi, that may be an indicator that something is wrong with the network setup though.

Comment: Are you sure your plc support port `34964`?